# Add comma separated input to table column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that have three column in it

```
Agent_Listing_Company>-
ListingId, AgentId, CompanyId
```

I want to insert comma separated input in it. My input is like

```
ListingId = '5',  AgentId = '6,7,8', CompanyId = '9,10,11'
```

I am using this query for insertion but its not working

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Agent_Listing_Company
                        (  ListingId ,
                          AgentId ,
                          CompanyId
                        )
                        SELECT  5, item ,
                                (select item from dbo.fn_split('9,10,11' , ','))
                        FROM    dbo.fn_split('6,7,8', ',')
```

--Here dbo.fn_split('6,7,8', ',')split my CompanyIds, But how do i split two inputs. 
My saved value after insertion in the table should be

```
ListingId, AgentId, CompanyId
   5         6          9
   5         7          10
   5         8          11
```

My dbo.fn_split('6,7,8', ',') function is...

```
USE [XRC]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_split]    Script Date: 6/3/2015 10:04:07 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER function [dbo].[fn_split](
@str varchar(max),
@delimiter char(1)
)
returns @returnTable table (idx int primary key identity, item varchar(8000))
as
begin
declare @pos int
select @str = @str + @delimiter
while len(@str) > 0 
begin
    select @pos = charindex(@delimiter,@str)
    if @pos = 1
        insert @returnTable (item)
            values (null)
    else
        insert @returnTable (item)
            values (substring(@str, 1, @pos-1))
    select @str = substring(@str, @pos+1, len(@str)-@pos)       
end
return
end
```

Comment: which data type your column hold ?if you wan to insert comma separated values then directly insert it into column why you split it ?if you use split function then it will separate those and return more than one rows

Comment: Using comma delimited strings to insert multiple values to tables is probably not the best choice. depending on the client (meaning the code that actually uses the insert statement), you might be able to send the values in a table valued parameter instead of comma delimited strings.

Comment: your question is little bit confusing what is your goal ? you want to insert data as 6,7,8 in a single row ?? or you want to split it based on comma and insert it into 3 rows like first row 6 second 7 third 8 likewise??

Comment: Insertion result should be like                                                                 ListingId, AgentId, CompanyId
   5         6          9
   5         7          10
   5         8          11

Comment: as mention in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into Agent_Listing_Company (  ListingId ,
                          AgentId ,
                          CompanyId
                        )
SELECT  5, a.item , b.item
FROM dbo.fn_split('6,7,8', ',') a
inner join dbo.fn_split('9,10,11' , ',') as b on a.idx = b.idx
```

Comment: I have used the distinct key word after select and its working. thnx

Answer (score 1):

This one uses `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Agent_Listing_Company(
    ListingId,
    AgentId,
    CompanyId
)
SELECT 
    5, s1.item, s2.item
FROM  dbo.fn_split('6,7,8', ',') s1
INNER JOIN dbo.fn_split('9,10,11' , ',') s2
    on s2.idx = s1.idx
```

---

As a side note, your `split` function is slow. It's doing the split in an `RBAR` fashion. You should replace it with a set-based approach. Read this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden for one of the fastest set-based splitter there is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multple record in single go then you should use [TVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) (Table Value Parameter). It will make your insertion fast and reliable.

Following things you need to do in your code:

1. Create Table data type having ListingId, AgentId, CompanyId columns in DB.
2. Create data table with same schema in your code (.Net).
3. Add record in data table and pass this tvp as input param in sproc.

So your data table having straight data as you want to input. for e,g

```
ListingId  AgentId  CompanyId
   5         6          9
   5         7          10
   5         8          11
```

I know it is little bit hard to understand, it will make easier for multiple insertion and updation any time.

Comment: What if the code is PHP, or ASP3? This is probably the correct solution for .Net clients, but the client was not mentioned in the question at all...